# find average of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, average

I am trying to find the average of just the females in the given array

```
sortArray([
    {name:'Sarah', gender:'female', age:25},
    {name:'Tom', gender:'male', age:18},
    {name:'Tim', gender:'male', age:65},
    {name:'Kim', gender:'female', age:58}
]);
```

this is what i have below

```
function averageFemale(list)
{
    let sum = 0;
    let femaleCount = 2;
    let avg = sum / femaleCount;

    for (let i = 0, i < list.length; i++)
    {
        sum += list[i];
    }

    return avg;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to average their ages? Because if so, then you really should, at some point in your function, use their ages.

Comment: you are trying to solve a this codewars kata :D https://www.codewars.com/kata/5aa1931311dbd9358b000823/train/javascript

Answer (score 42):

You can filter out "females" to a new array, and then reduce that down to a total of all ages, then use the length of the females array to divide the total by:

```js
const people = [{name:'Sarah', gender:'female', age:25}, {name:'Tom', gender:'male', age:18}, {name:'Tim', gender:'male', age:65}, {name:'Kim', gender:'female', age:58}];

const females = people.filter(person => person.gender === 'female');

const average = females.reduce((total, next) => total + next.age, 0) / females.length;

console.log(average);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also:

- Filter the input array using `.filter()` to get only objects having `gender` as `female`.
- Use `.reduce()` to get the sum of ages.
- Calculate average by dividing the above calculated sum by the numbers of objects in filtered array.

**Demo:**

```js
let data = [
  {name:'Sarah', gender:'female', age:25},
  {name:'Tom', gender:'male', age:18},
  {name:'Tim', gender:'male', age:65},
  {name:'Kim', gender:'female', age:58}
];

let filteredData = data.filter(({ gender }) => gender == 'female'),
    avg = filteredData.reduce((r, c) => r + c.age, 0) / filteredData.length;
                 
console.log(avg);
```

Comment: If you wanted to one-line this then you could consider using the source-array argument in the reducing function and divide c.age by the array length before accumulating. i.e: reduce((r,c,i,a)=> r+c.age/a.length,0)

Answer (score 4):

```js
const arr= [
    {name:'Sarah', gender:'female', age:25},
    {name:'Tom', gender:'male', age:18},
    {name:'Tim', gender:'male', age:65},
    {name:'Kim', gender:'female', age:58}
]


function averageAgeByGender(array,gender){
  const getGender = (elem) => elem.gender===gender
  const average = (a,b, i, self)=> (a+b.age/self.length)
  return array.filter(getGender).reduce(average,0)
}

console.log(averageAgeByGender(arr,'female'))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the gender before adding the age to `sum`, and also increment `femaleCount` instead of hard-coding it to `2`.

There's also no need to re-calculate `avg` every time through the loop, you can do it once at the end.

```js
function averageFemale(list) {
  let sum = 0;
  let femaleCount = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].gender == 'female') {
      sum += list[i].age;
      femaleCount++;
    }
  }
  if (femaleCount == 0) {
    return 0; // prevent division by 0
  }
  let avg = sum / femaleCount;
  return avg;
}

console.log(averageFemale([{name:'Sarah', gender:'female', age:25}, {name:'Tom', gender:'male', age:18}, {name:'Tim', gender:'male', age:65}, {name:'Kim', gender:'female', age:58}]));
```

You also had a typo in the `for` loop header, `,` should be `;`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with a single reduce

```js
function averageBy(arr) {
    const {total, count} = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
            if (b.gender === 'female') {
                a.total += b.age;
                a.count++;
            }
            return a;
        }, {total: 0, count: 0});
    
    return total / count;
}

console.log(averageBy(arr));
```

```html
<script>
const arr = [
    {
        name: 'Sarah',
        gender: 'female',
        age: 25
    },
    {
        name: 'Tom',
        gender: 'male',
        age: 18
    },
    {
        name: 'Tim',
        gender: 'male',
        age: 65
    },
    {
        name: 'Kim',
        gender: 'female',
        age: 58
    }
];
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the `gender` property and take sum `age` and increment a counter, because you do not know that in advance.

```js
function averageFemale(list) {
    var sum = 0,
        count = 0,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].gender === 'female') {
            sum += list[i].age;
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return sum / count;
}

var array = [{ name: 'Sarah', gender: 'female', age: 25 }, { name: 'Tom', gender: 'male', age: 18 }, { name: 'Tim', gender: 'male', age: 65 }, { name: 'Kim', gender: 'female', age: 58 }];

console.log(averageFemale(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, which I find more flexible:

```
function sumOfArrayWithParameter (array, parameter) {
  let sum = null;
  if (array && array.length > 0 && typeof parameter === 'string') {
    sum = 0;
    for (let e of array) if (e && e.hasOwnProperty(parameter)) sum += e[parameter];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

To get the average, you'd simply use it like that:

```
let sum = sumOfArrayWithParameter(array, 'age');
let avg = sum / array.length;
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it by reducing the age of the females and dividing by total females:

```js
const data = [{name:'Sarah', gender:'female', age:25}, {name:'Tom', gender:'male', age:18}, {name:'Tim', gender:'male', age:65}, {name:'Kim', gender:'female', age:58}];

let count = 0;
const average = data.reduce((total, person) => {
  if (person.gender === 'female') {
   total += person.age;
    count++;
  }
  return total;
}, 0) / count;

console.log(average);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just my approach (**looping only once on the array**), and based on the next mathematical formula for progressive calculation of average:

```
avgN = (x1 + ... + xN) / N = (x1 + ... + xN-1) / N + (xN / N)

     = (x1 + ... + xN-1) * (N-1) / (N * (N-1)) + (xN / N)

     = ((x1 + ... + xN-1) / (N-1)) * ((N-1) / N) + (xN / N)

     = avgN-1 * (N-1) / N + (xN / N)

     = ((N-1) avgN-1 + xN) / N
```

```js
var sortArray = [
    {name:'Sarah', gender:'female', age:25},
    {name:'Tom', gender:'male', age:18},
    {name:'Tim', gender:'male', age:65},
    {name:'Kim', gender:'female', age:58}
];

function averageFemale(list)
{
    var count = 0;

    return list.reduce((avg, personData) =>
    {
        if (personData.gender === 'female')
            avg = (count * avg + personData.age) / (++count);

        return avg;
    },0);
}

console.log("Average age of females is: " + averageFemale(sortArray));
```